# event data inside settimeout function is null in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have a react function

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.playVideo(e, name)}>
```

tried with both options

```
playVideo(event, name) {
    console.log(event, 'event details');
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(event, 'event details inside timeout'); 
    }, 1500)
}
```

```
playVideo(event, name) {
    console.log(event, 'event details');
    setTimeout(function (event) {
      console.log(event, 'event details inside timeout'); 
    }, 1500)
}
```

In the above code the initial event is working as expected but I need the event data inside settimout bcaz I have to load few js files based on the event, but event data inside settimeout function is always null.

I have also tried with **onClickCapture** but still no luck

```
<button onClickCapture={(e) => this.playVideo(e, name)}>
```

Comment: setTimeout doesn't pass any arguments to the callback, unless set as 2+n arguments of the setTimeout call.

Comment: The `event` variable declared in the outer `playVideo` callback scope is *still* in scope in the inner `setTimeout` callback. It's covered in the enclosures of both callbacks (provided you don't overshadow it in the inner callback).

Comment: You don't need event parameter in setTimeout callback function. You already can access event parameter, just leave callback function with empty parameters.

Comment: @DrewReese 

When I console the event inside setTimeout() fn without 'event' parameter its returning null

When I console the event inside setTimeout(event) fn with 'event' parameter its returning 'undefined'

Comment: And you are sure you did pass it as `event` inside `playVideo`? `window.event` is also a thing (a monstrous thing at this), so you could very well be referencing that thing in the true event handler, which wouldn't exist anymore in the timeout handler, but that's not what happens in the shown code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to `React-v17` you need the values to be in scope due to [Syntethic Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) wrapper used in React:

```
playVideo(event) => {
    const { currentTarget } = event;

    // closure on currentTarget won't lose due to synthetic event.
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(currentTarget, 'event details inside timeout'); 
    }, 1500)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) callback with additional parameters in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Just add `event` object in parameter after `}, 1500, event)` and it will be available in `callback`.

```
playVideo(event, name) {
    console.log(event, 'event details');
    setTimeout(function (event) {
      console.log(event, 'event details inside timeout'); 
    }, 1500, event) // <- Pass event object from here
}
```

---

**Edit** As per the suggestion from [@Felix King in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575013/event-data-inside-settimeout-function-is-null/65575063#comment115938345_65575063) you can use `event` object from parent scope `playVideo` with just remove parameter in `callback` like below.

```
playVideo(event, name) {
    console.log(event, 'event details');
    setTimeout(function () { // <- Do no add event parameter so event object will be fetch from parent scope.
      console.log(event, 'event details inside timeout'); 
    }, 1500)
}
```

Comment: Why not just access `playVideo`'s `event` parameter directly?

Comment: @FelixKling, That is also a solution. Updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @FelixKling as im implementing it in reactJs events are overridden by react synthetic events, that's the reason im getting null inside setTimeout()

Comment: @SwaroopGuptaVoleti: Which version of React are you using? *"As of v17, e.persist() doesn’t do anything because the SyntheticEvent is no longer pooled."* What information of the event do you need to access?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm using react v16.6.3 and im trying to accessing `event.currentTarget`

Comment: @SwaroopGuptaVoleti: Then just do `const {currentTarget} = event;` in the first line of the event handler and access `currentTarget` directly inside the `setTimeout` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass `event` parameter to settimeout function because it considered to be a local variable in this scope.